# how to get prediction value using trained model using keras?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I want to use the learned model to get a new prediction.
SO i made a function what i want to get.
But it doesn't work.
When i using this function, it always return same values.
I think there's a problem with the encoding procedure, but I don't know how to solve it.
I changed lot of things what i doubted but it doesn't work.
Please watch this code, and please tell me what is the problem in this code.
thank you.

```
def determineRank(t,n,bid_t,w,h,k):
#    t = str(input())   # time
#    n = int(input())   # now ranking
#    bid_t = int(input())   # bid amount
#    w = int(input())   # weekday
#    h = int(input())   # holiday
#    k = str(input())   # keyword


    encode = LabelEncoder()
    #x = np.concatenate((t,n,bid_t,w,h,k),axis = 1).reshape(1,6,1)
    t = categorize_time(t)
    k = encode.fit_transform([k])
    new_list = []
    new_list = [t,n,bid_t,w,h,k]

    """ 
    new_list = new_list.append(t)
    new_list = new_list.append(n)
    new_list = new_list.append(bid_t)
    new_list = new_list.append(w)
    new_list = new_list.append(h)
    new_list = new_list.append(k)
    k = encode.fit_transform(k)
    """

    new_list = np.array(new_list)   
    new_list = new_list.reshape(1,6,1)
    model = load_model('03-0.728448.hdf5')
    rank = model.predict(new_list)
    return rank[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is problem with the encoding procedure.
When you call the `LabelEncoder ()`, you create a new encoder. So for any value that is passed to the new encoder, the encoded result will be the same. To predict by encoder-based value, you should use the same encoder as for model fitting:

1. Fit:

```py
    ...
    encode = LabelEncoder()  # create new encoder
    k = encode.fit_transform([k])  # fit encoder and transform value
    save_encoder(encode, 'some_name_for_encoder.hdf5')  # save fitted encoder for further usage
    ...
```

2. Predict:

```py
    ...
    encode = load_encoder('some_name_for_encoder.hdf5')  # load fitted encoder
    k = encode.transform([k])  # transform value
    ...
```